# Bounding $L^2$ norm of projection operator by inner product with arbitrary vector in projected subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, projection

Let $W$ be a subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ and let $P$ be a self-adjoint orthogonal projection operator onto $W$. Let $v \in H$. Then is it true that for any  $w \in W$ with $||w||_2 = 1$, we have
$$||Pv||_2 \leq |\langle v, w \rangle|?$$

This inequality seems weird to me since for example the LHS doesn't depend on $w$. At first I thought this was just Parseval in the sense that
$$||Pv||_2^2 = \sum_{e_n} |\langle Pv, e_n \rangle|^2 = \sum_{e_n} |\langle v, P^\ast e_n\rangle|^2 = \sum_{f_n} |\langle v, f_n\rangle|^2,$$ where $e_n$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$ and $f_n$ is an orthonormal basis for $W$. Then writing $w = \sum_n \alpha_n f_n$ where $\alpha_n = \langle w, f_n\rangle$, we have
$$|\langle v, w \rangle|^2 = | \sum_n \alpha_n \langle v, f_n \rangle|^2 = \sum_{n,m} \alpha_m \alpha_n \langle v, f_m\rangle \langle v, f_n \rangle \geq \sum_{n} \alpha_n^2 |\langle v, f_n\rangle|^2.$$

If I knew that each $\alpha_n^2$ was at least $1$, I could conclude the inequality. It seems like the original inequality might only be true if $W$ is a one-dimensional subspace. Generally such Bessel-type arguments seem to give inequalities in the wrong direction. However, it may be enough for my purposes to have a bound of the form
$$||Pv||_2 \ll |\langle v, w\rangle|,$$
though I am curious if the original inequality holds and whether there is a simple proof. I also don't use that $||w||_2 = 1$ anywhere and I wonder whether that is essential.

Comment: By $L^{2}$ norm I suppose you just mean the norm in the Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v \in W, v \neq 0$ and $w \in W$ be a unit vector orthogonal to $v$. Then the inequality says $\|v\| \leq | \langle v, w \rangle|=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't think this can happen. I want P to be an orthogonal projection so that $W + W^\perp = H$ and so the inner product between two vectors in $W$ can't be zero.

Comment: @StephCurry Suppose $H=\mathbb R^{3}, W=span \{e_1,e_2\}$. Then $W^{\perp}=span (e_3)$. $e_1$ and $e_2$ are orthogonal unit vectors in $W$ right?

Comment: Ah sorry, I see. Yes you're completely right.